# Ruby shorten an if statement: if item present THEN look for attribute on item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now my if statement looks like this:

```
if User.find(user[:id]).present? && User.find(user[:id]).status_id != nil
   ...
end
```

So if a `User` is found, then check its `status_id`. The reason it's like this is because I don't want an exception thrown when I'm checking status_id on an User that can't be found. But wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this...

Comment: `if User.find(user[:id]).try(:status_id) != nil` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence), which was designed exactly for this sort of scenario:

```
if User.find_by_id(user[:id]).try(:status_id) != nil
```

From the docs:

> Invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like `public_send` does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it the call returns nil rather than raising an exception.
>
> This method is defined to be able to write
>
> ```
> @person.try(:name)
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> @person.name if @person
> ```

I also changed `User.find` to `User.find_by_id`, since that returns `nil` if a record isn't found (instead of raising an exception).

Comment: this would raise an exception of not found if it cant find the user, thats why I proposed this solution in the answer `User.exists?(id: user[:id], status_id: !nil)` which does work

Comment: @ZaidQureshi Oops; that's what you get for not actually testing code :-/ Fixed it by changing `find` to `find_by_id`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

.find throw an exception if not found.

Try this instead:

```
user = User.where(id: user[:id]).first
if user.present? && user.status_id != nil
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a user object, so use it directly instead of querying the database again:

```
if !user.status_id.nil?
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Active Record documentation says

> The find method will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception
>   unless a matching record is found for all of the supplied primary
>   keys.

It looks like you may want the first method instead, as it doesn't raise an exception.